# замена подстрок строки с помощью регулярного выражения javascript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

дана строка:

```
let str =
'{{ name }} is here. {{ name }} is playing {{ game }}. he is {{ age }}'
```

объект:

```
const obj = { name: 'Petro', game: 'Mortal Comabt', age: 27 }
```

В строке необходимо шаблоны, совпадающие с ключами объекта, заменить с помощью регулярного выражения.

Мое решение:

```
const arr = Object.keys(obj)
arr.forEach((item) => {
  str = str.replace(new RegExp(`({{ ${item} }})`, 'g'), `${obj[item]}`)
})

console.log(str)
```

Возможно ли решение без перебора массива (forEach)?

есть ощущение что решение близко:

```
console.log(str.replace(new RegExp('({{ (\\w+) }})', 'g'), 'obj.$2'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```js
/{{\s+(\w+)\s+}}/g
```

**Подробности**

- `{{` - строка `{{`
- `\s+` - один и более проебельных символов
- `(\w+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: одна и более букв, цифр или знаков подчёркивания
- `\s+` - один и более проебельных символов
- `}}` - строка `}}`.

```js
let str = '{{ name }} is here. {{ name }} is playing {{ game }}. he is {{ age }}. Note: {{ word }} is an unknown placeholder.';
const obj = { name: 'Petro', game: 'Mortal Comabt', age: 27 }
console.log(
    str.replace(/{{\s+(\w+)\s+}}/g, (match, group) => obj[group] || match)
)
```

Обратите внимание, с помощью флага `g` осуществляется поиск всех совпадений в строке. В качестве замены используется `(match, group) => obj[group] || match)`, где  `match` — текст целого совпадения, а `group` — текст захватывающей подмаски №1. Если подмаска "сработала", нашла совпадение, то возвращается соответствующее значение `obj`, иначе возвращается текст целого совпадения.

Answer (score 1):

```
let str =
'{{ name }} is here. {{ name }} is playing {{ game }}. he is {{ age }}'
const obj = { name: 'Petro', game: 'Mortal Comabt', age: 27 }    

str = str.replace(new RegExp(`{{ (\\w+) }}`, 'g'), (_, val) => obj[val] || _)
console.log(str)
```

Comment: как называется первый аргумент в стрел. функции? Хочу разобраться и почитать за него

Comment: почитайте про RegExp, там все описано. Если кратко, то первый элемент - это найденное полное сопоставление по регулярному выражению. В примере это поочередно будут строки: '{{ name }}', '{{ name }}', '{{ game }}' и '{{ age }}'. Во втором параметре будет то, что соответствует $1 - найденное в круглых скобках

Comment: (_, val) =>.... подчеркивание здесь первым аргументом - что за оператор/инструкция?

Comment: это просто имя параметра. Его можно назвать как угодно